# Не работает page.php WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Не отображается страница page.php.
Пишу свой шаблон, дошел до отдельных страниц и тут выясняется, что page.php не работает, от слова совсем. Даже в "Twenty Seventeen". Код самого движка не трогал, только свой шаблон исправлял.
Куда можно копнуть? Может, что в настройках не так?

Comment: Информации, конечно, маловато. Попробуйте поочерёдно отключать плагины.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6688/220220

Comment: @Pyramidhead, с плагинами не помогло? Я кажется не совсем правильно использую page.php, но при переходе на сайт/page открывается страница 404. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Послушайте, что за постановка вопроса: page.php не работает в Twenty Seventeen? Там все работает. Удалите свой код, поставьте тему заново. Опишите ваши действия, которыми вы сломали тему, и конкретную ошибку. Тогда можно будет о чем-то говорить. А пока голосую за закрытие вопроса, как бессодержательного.

Comment: 1. page.php это НЕ страница, а шаблон. 
2. Шаблон не может не подключиться, если не нарушена работа ВП. Ибо [иерархия оных](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) - есть закон. 
3. рано тебе создавать свои темы. Используй правильные из [оф каталога](https://wordpress.org/themes/) и [механизм дочерних](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: @KoliK, если при переходе на сайт у вас ошибка 404, то просто зайдите в админку, затем Настройки > Постоянные ссылки и нажмите "Сохранить изменения".